# Misalignment of bullets on vote-to-close sequence

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close

The first vote-to-close dialog lists the radio buttons next to the selection:

[image]

When selecting **off-topic because**, the radio buttons are vertically misaligned:

[image]

Can this be fixed?